# Error (error C2064) while calling function through function pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, function-pointers, boolean-logic

The exact error I received was:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

I'm trying to create a basic logic gate simulation tool. This is just part of the basic logic, this is my first project of this scale. what I've included below is the code for one gate class, an AND gate class will inherit properties from this base class. My error Occurs at the function pointer call.

```
class gate
{
    protected:

    short int A,B;//These variables represent the two inputs to the Gate.

    public:

    short int R;//This variable stores the result of the Gate

    gate *input_1, *input_2;//Pointers to Inputs

    void (gate::*operationPtr)();

    void doAND()//Does AND operation
    {
        R=A&&B;
        operationPtr=&gate::doAND;
    }

    short int getResult()
    {
        operationPtr();//ERROR OCCURS HERE
        return R;
    }

};
```

Comment: But are you sure that member function pointers are really what you want here? Wouldn't derived classes with virtual functions solve the same problem in a simpler way?

Comment: I'll implement this change for now, I'll look into using virtual functions although I'm a little sketchy on how exactly to go about calling them. I'll do some homework on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`operationPtr` is a *pointer to member function,* not a *pointer to function.* This means that to dereference it, you must also supply an object on which to invoke the function. You probably meant this:

```
short int getResult()
{
    (this->*operationPtr)();
    return R;
}
```